# Button not displaying until MouseOver

Tags: actionscript-3, cellrenderer

I have a CustomCellRenderer for a TileList that has a button on the cell. The button does not display except for the label text on the button. Once I mouse over the button it displays like normal again. I'm not doing anything fancy with the button, simply adding it as a child of the cell. I had to set the `mouseChildren = true;` for the customcellrenderer to even get the mouseover to work, so I'm guessing there is something funky about a customcellrenderer with a TileList?

Answer (score 0):

```
buttonName.drawNow()
```

That will force the button to redraw :) That solves this issue.